# When using sync framework how are changes tracked client side when using SQL Server Change Tracking server-side?

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to sync up my SQL Server Compact db with a SQL Server 2008 R2 db using MS Sync Framework. I'm using the Change Tracking option which operates server-side. But how/where are changes tracked client-side?

Answer (score 3):

If you inspect the SQL CE database you'll find that tables have been added:

- __syncArticles
- __syncSubscriptions
- __syncTransactions

### sample data:

__syncArticles table

```
TableName   SentAnchor             ReceivedAnchor                                                                                                            ClientId
Order       0xBF01000000000000  0x0001000000FFFFFFFF010000000000000004010000000C53797374656D2E496E74363401000000076D5F76616C75650009E5220000000000000B  53656560-a50a-4e4b-8f04-04f16a4ca538
```

__syncSubscriptions table

```
ClientId                            ServerId                            MachineId
53656560-a50a-4e4b-8f04-04f16a4ca538    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    43eac8b2-00f3-46d2-8297-e69b277d5590
```

__syncTransactions table

```
SyncBsn
469
```

Comment: Right, I did notice those things. I wasn't sure if they were still used with the server Change Tracking setting. Does anyone know of any resources that explain how those particular tables work? Anyways, thank you for the help.

Comment: @Chris  I had the same question - I can see the three tables added, but there is no documentation for how they work...